# Hibernate/JDBC dynamic/ad hoc table generation possible?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-jdbc

We have a requirement where we want to automatically parse CSV files and insert them to a table. We are exploring if it is possible to generate a table on the fly, using an ORM such as Hibernate.

For example, a new CSV file is found, downloaded, and in our code we would parse the columns, create a new table, and insert the data.

Obviously there's a lot of red flags to this approach, but we're in the early stages of figuring out what options we have.

Comment: It really depends on what you need, what degree of scalability, data throughput, infra, time available... I would suggest using a keep it simple strategy, the approach you suggested doesn't seem bad at all to me, it just needs to be further detailed and broken down in smaller tasks that you will be able to describe. Then you'll be able to see if there's an existing library/application to help you.

Comment: @eduardohl thanks. Do you know if creating tables during runtime is possible?

Comment: Yes it is, pretty doable, even if not an standard approach. If your tables will tend to change a lot due to CSV format using a schemaless db is a good solution as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can automatically generate a schema from a set of JPA-annoated classes, or vice versa. The primary goal of Hibernate is to map between Java POJOs and a relational database, hence the term "Object Relational Mapping". If you don't know anything about the tables or the columns compile time, I would suggest to generate the tables and insert statements using plain JDBC. If you want some support, you can give Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)) a try.

If you're in a really green stage, a document database like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) might solve your problem better than a relational database. You will not have to worry about column names at the time of insertion, just convert the CSV-file to JSON (there are several tools available online, google it) and insert the result to a collection. You will of course have an easier time querying the data if there is some consistency between the documents in a collection.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also thought of semi/unstructured data, but was told to explore dumping it into a structured DB. I agree about the part about ORM's mapping entities to tables, which is why I'm doubtful about ad hoc table generation.

Comment: Do you know a way to perhaps parse the csv columns into numeric or strings in mongo?

Comment: The mongoimport utility (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) might provide some help if you don't want to code the import yourself. If you're making a parser in Java I would advice you to look at Jackson or gson for parsing, and JsonPath for queries and lookups (if necessary). 

On the note of exploring relational database alternatives, you might find this blog post interesting: http://www.itexto.com.br/devkico/en/?p=60